# Android wait for GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Im using GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener to get the current location (below)

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        start = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start));
    }
};
```

However, I need a way to wait for the listener to complete. Reason being that, Start var will obviously be null if I continue to execute other code without location data. I thought that AsyncTask might be useful here, but have no idea what to call inside doInBackground/onPostExecute.

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener); // set the listener
// perform wait and initiate start variable
String url = getDirectionsUrl(start, destination);
// a sync task here using the url
```

Any hints or code snippets would be much appreciated~!

Comment: What part of your code do you need to wait for? Is it possible to use conditional statements to skip that code until start != null.

Comment: I doubt thats an option. I need the location information after setting the listener. =>
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
String url = getDirectionsUrl(start, destination);

Comment: What you could do is set your Listener, create a method that does what you want to do after your have gotten your location, and then in `onMyLocationChange(Location location)` call that method instead of just letting the code run even though you know you won't have the value you need. This way you will pause the functionality until you are certain you have your `start` value without blocking up the UI thread.

Comment: Hmm that works >< beating myself for not figuring this out myself... thank you sir.

Comment: No problem, I do recommend looking into FusedLocationProvider as that is the recommended method now. You should be able to implement your current fix into a FusedLocationProvider fairly simply, the samples provided by Android are pretty straight forward. Happy coding :)

Comment: @KaiteN  I just wrote up a detailed answer on how to use FusedLocationProvider in conjunction with a SupportMapFragment, it might help if you decide to go down that path:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253123/blue-dot-and-circle-is-not-shown-on-mylocation-using-android-fused-location-api/30255219#30255219

Comment: Already moved to Fused as CommonsWare suggested :) thanks Daniel, good stuff!

Comment: Regarding fused location, I can recommend this library : https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation

Answer (score 2):

> I need the location information after setting the listener

That is not possible. There may not *be* any "location information after setting the listener". It may take some time to get a location fix. Given your existing code, your first opportunity to have location data will be in `onMyLocationChange()`, and you cannot use the location data before that point.

Also note that `setOnMyLocationChangeListener()` has been deprecated for about a year. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMyLocationChangeListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener%29):

> This method is deprecated.
>   use FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or the Location Developer Guide.

Comment: Do you have an example how it should be used?

Comment: @yehyatt: If you mean the fused location API, then yes: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location

Comment: OnMyLocationChangeListener is depreciated what is alternate??