# How to add Google Map Markers outside of onMapReady() in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have the following function that returns me the current location of device:

```
void getCurrentLocation()
{
    Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
    if(myLocation!=null)
    {
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to fetch the current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but some methods are showing in red like it were undefined:
[image: this]

As you can notice, these methods are related with map, it work in onMapReady() function but out of it show it unrecognized. Why is that? What libraries I have to add? I declare map like this:

```
private MapFragment map;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what your general code structure should look like.
The important part is to assign your local `map` reference to the one returned in the `onMapReady()` callback.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap retMap) {

        map = retMap;

        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap(){

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    void getCurrentLocation()
    {
        Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
        if(myLocation!=null)
        {
            double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                    .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to fetch the current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where I can put `getCurrentLocation()` ?

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad This way of getting location is deprecated, if you want to get the current location for a map, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253123/blue-dot-and-circle-is-not-shown-on-mylocation-using-android-fused-location-api

Comment: Thank you, I'm unable to get current location in android studio, emulator 5554, I used `geo fix xxx xxxx`, all other possible ways but failed.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad It sounds like you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator  I would recommend using a real device for testing location based code.....

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
 private MapFragment map;
```

Your map should be of type

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
```

Just change

```
private MapFragment map;
```

to

```
private GoogleMap map;
```

and get the map like the following:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

It will work fine.

Comment: what´s the way to declarate google map?  i was using         map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
to asign this but I change to Google map and give me an error because are different types

Comment: @ReneLimon Updated the answer. Check the last  line.

Comment: one last question, getMap is not deprecated?

Comment: @ReneLimon Yeah sorry, It's deprecated. Use `getMapAsync()` and `onMapReady()` returns the map object and It's guaranteed to be `not null`.

Comment: @karthik actually, it can´t be onMapAsync because are diferent types I following Daniel Nugent steps