# Security Exception only on Android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to perform any location operations.
```

The app works fine for Android version 5(Lollipop) but gets a Security Exception on the Android version 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your activity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION=0
...
loadPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Implementation:

```
private void loadPermissions(String perm,int requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, perm)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{perm},requestCode);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // granted
            }
            else{
                // no granted
            }
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In the `loadPermissions()` function, shouldn't there be an `else` clause (when `checkSelfPermission()` returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` where you do your permission-wise stuff? `onRequestPermissionsResult()` will be invoked only after calling `requestPermissions()`, so in the case I described nothing will happen.

Comment: Is only the main idea an example, maybe in some situations you have write "else" implementation.

Answer (score 16):

This is because these permissions are dangerous permission as per new permission model of android 6.0.

dangerous permissions need to be asked for at run time and should be checked every time before usage.

you will have to change your implementation to [adapt new permission model](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Usually this should just be necessary if you're targeting API 23+. However we've also encountered these kind of exceptions on Android 6. Guess there's a bug in Android's fallback implementation.