# Permission exception even though permission is set in manifest

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

However, when I run my app and press the button that needs this permission I get the following exception:

```
Geofence usage requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
```

How can I fix this?

I have the permission right under `<manifest>`

I am using Android 6.

This is my code:

```
   public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    // The GeofenceRequest object.
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                    // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                    // transition is observed.
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
            logSecurityException(securityException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have put your permission in a wrong `Element` in your Manifest

Comment: I have the permission right under <manifest>

Comment: post your full manifest, And are you using 6.0 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using 6.0.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063712/security-exception-only-on-android-6/33063733#33063733

Comment: I added my code, where I need the permission

Comment: To request this permission, add the following element as a child element of the <manifest> element in your app manifest: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 1):

When compiling for API 23 you have to ask for that Permission.

Theres a good Blog Post about that: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/09/google-play-services-81-and-android-60.html