# Get Current Location on Google Map not working properly?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I am take my current location for put marker on map its working properly but some time its not working properly i don't know why help me to find out my fault in this code. This is my code for take current location and put marker on map.

This is my java file `MapActivity.java`

```
try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL).compassEnabled(false)
                .rotateGesturesEnabled(false).tiltGesturesEnabled(false);

        // this is for get current location
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(
                        criteria, true));

        if (location != null) {
            currentLatLng = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude()));

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                            .getLongitude()), 13));

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(currentLatLng));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(currentLatLng).zoom(12)
                    .bearing(90).tilt(40).build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                    .center(currentLatLng).radius(200)
                    .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    .strokeColor(0x10000000).strokeWidth(5);

            mCircle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's not completely clear where you're having problems.  However, using `getLastKnownLocation()` is not very reliable.  Best to explicitly request a location update when you need it, take a look at the code in this answer that uses FusedLocationProviderApi: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409

Comment: oky thnax let me see where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 1):

After calling animateCamera() ,you need to call **setMyLocationEnabled(true)** e.g

```
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                            .getLongitude()), 13));
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following line of code?

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```