# Get user current location from android Map Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I have a Map Activity (the android studio default) which looks like

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{...}
```

I need to get the user's current location. Do I still have to use

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
```

which would mean keeping an instance of `mGoogleApiClient` or can I use the `mMap` field to generate the current location?

Now I understand if the user clicks on the myLocation button **then** I can get the location with `mMap.getMyLocation`; but I am interested in the non-trivial case where the user has not clicked the button. How do I get the current location in such case?

Comment: All ways of getting a location from the map reference have been deprecated.  The current advise from Google is to use FusedLocationApi for all location based functionality in your app.  For implementation see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219

Comment: I see. Thank you. +1