# Android: Get current coordinates in real-time using google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I tried several tutorials but no luck getting current coordinates, maybe i cant follow or really dont know how to set up one.

Sorry for being newbie. I just want to create an app that will get current location thru gps, whether location is change or not. I can manage to get the last known location but cannot implement to get real-time coordinates. 
It will be much appreciated to have a whole source that will show the solution. I get easily lost in part by part code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide links to the tutorials you tried and tell us where you got stuck in those tutorials.

Comment: At the risk of being self-promoting:  http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Comment: If you want to use LocationManager, use Gabe's GPSTracker.  If you want to use FusedLocationProviderApi, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409

Comment: @DanielNugent On my to do list one of these days-  write a switcher class that uses Fused if it is installed, and falls back to LocationManager if it doesn't.  API is similar enough it ought not be too hard.  I just need to find freetime, so probably 2017.

Comment: @GabeSechan That would be awesome!  I would definitely use that if you write it!

Comment: @Aaron, i watched several video tutorials in youtube, cant remember the specific link, sorry.

Comment: @Gabe and Daniel, thank you so much, both links show full source code  :) it will help a lot in my study

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both links provide useful code

For LocationManager, visit this link: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/ ([Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan))

For FusedLocationProviderApi, visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409 ( [Daniel Nugent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409409/daniel-nugent))