# Android Maps onLocationChanged problems

Tags: android, google-maps, events

Im having problems with my current code, i don't see what i'm doing wrong. i keep getting the error "no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(string,int,in,MapsActivity)

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener, DirectionCallback, OnMapClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private LocationManager locationManager;
private Button btnRequestDirection;
GPSTracker gps;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private String serverKey = "xxx";
private LatLng camera = new LatLng(54.1111, -1.1111);
private LatLng origin = new LatLng(54.1111, -1.1111);
private LatLng destination = new LatLng(54.11, -1.11);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
    long i = 1000;
    long x = 10;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,i,x, this);


    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        camera = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
        origin = camera;


        btnRequestDirection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_request_direction);
        btnRequestDirection.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}
```

Everything i do the event  "onLocationChanged()" never triggers, =/

Comment: Have a look at the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409

Comment: Brilliant Thanks this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a locationListener to listen for a location changes. If you are using  ['requestLocationUpdates'](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), you must use 'import android.location.LocationListener'. The standard Android location stuffs is 'android.location'. The com.google.android.gms.location stuff is for use with the  [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#public-methods) which is part of Google play services.