# Android current location marker ID (name)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-markers, location-services

I am pretty much a novice at Android development, so please feel free to describe in very simple terms any advice you may give in response to my query.

I would like my application to start by displaying an Activity zoomed out to an extent that shows both my current location and that of a marker that I have placed on a map some distance from me.

I have successfully placed and displayed the remote marker the on the map and have found this class:  LatLngBounds.Builder, which allows me to determine the bounds of all locations I am interested in, by supplying it the locations via its include method.

I obviously know the LatLng of my remote marker, but rather than going through the rigmarole of getting my current location using  Google Play services and the location services API was wondering if, as my location has already been determined and is being displayed as the standard Google small blue circle, by virtue of me having set map.setMyLocationEnabled(true), whether my code has access to this ‘marker’.  If it has, and I somehow know its ID, then could I not simply determine my location from [currentLocationBlueCircleMarker].getPosition()?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There used to be a way](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener) to get a Location from a GoogleMap object, but it has been deprecated:

> **com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener**
>
> This interface is deprecated. use
>   com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.
>   FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power
>   usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the
>   MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example
>   example code, or the Location Developer Guide.

So, you will need to use other means to get the current Location, though it's quite simple to get the current location using the FusedLocationProviderApi from Google Play Services.

For a complete example (targeting api-23 and up) see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409

For a complete example (targeting api-22 and down) see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409

Comment: Thank you for this and for the useful examples.