# Wrong type argument for PermissionCheck around GoogleMap OnMyLocationChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am working on an Android App that should use the Location of the user in a Google Map. However, the required permission check for the LocationManager fails in the context of the GoogleMap onMyLocationChangeListener method and I don´t know why. After heavy googling, I haven´t found a solution yet, so any hint or help would be warmly welcomed.

The Activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import gmbh.webagenten.CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap;

public class GoogleMapInfoWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int EDIT_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private LatLng getCurrentPosition() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();             // set criteria for location provider:
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);   // fine accuracy
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);                 // no monetary cost

        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, "current position: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return myPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        LatLng myPosition;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        if (location != null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 19);
            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
        }
        if (mMap != null) {

            // to set current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            /*markerOptions.position(myPosition)
                    .title("Hier bin ich")
                    .snippet("Snoqualmie Falls is located 25 miles east of Seattle.")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
*/

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
           /*LatLng snowqualmie = new LatLng(53.5621649, 9.9660802);

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(snowqualmie)
                    .title("Hier bin ich")
                    .snippet("Snoqualmie Falls is located 25 miles east of Seattle.")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

            InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData();
            info.setImage("snowqualmie");
            info.setHotel("Hotel : excellent hotels available");
            info.setFood("Food : all types of restaurants available");
            info.setTransport("Reach the site by bus, car and train.");

            CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap customInfoWindow = new CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(this);
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow);

            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            m.setTag(info);
            m.showInfoWindow();

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(snowqualmie));*/
        }

        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                List<String> providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
                if (null != locations && null != providerList && providerList.size() > 0) {
                    double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
                    double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                            String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));

                Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(150, 150, conf);
                Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);

                // paint defines the text color, stroke width and size
                Paint color = new Paint();
                color.setTextSize(30);
                color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

                // modify canvas
                canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.custom_marker), 0, 0, color);
                //canvas1.drawText("Your position", 20, 5, color);
                // add marker to Map
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(loc)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                        // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1).title("Your current position").snippet("You are here"));
            }
        };

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {
                Intent edit = new Intent(GoogleMapInfoWindowActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
                GoogleMapInfoWindowActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                    LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
                }
            };
        }
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            this.imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        switch (requestCode) {
            case (EDIT_REQUEST): {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = data.getParcelableExtra("marker");
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Android Studio Error message in line 164:

Wrong 1st argument type. Found:'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener', required:'android.content.Context'

Here´s what I tried so far:

- replacing "this" by getApplication, getApplicationContext and other by Android Studio suggested Context related methods -

none of this worked.

So, again, any help or hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener` is deprecated , see here for explanation and alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37282645/4409409 and the best current solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992014/how-to-get-current-location-in-googlemap-using-fusedlocationproviderclient

Comment: @DanielNugent: thanks a lot, that was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 164:

`if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {`

use `GoogleMapInfoWindowActivity.this` instead of only `this`

`if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GoogleMapInfoWindowActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {`

because `this` inside `new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener()` means `OnMyLocationChangeListener` not the `Activity/AppCompatActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use GoogleMap class context instead of your activity.